# Wordpress MySql INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to INSERT in wordpress through phpmydamin ... but my post is not being displayed to users.

In addition to the wp_posts table must insert any more?

This is my query...

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts (cod_empresa,post_author,post_date,post_date_gmt,post_content,post_title,post_excerpt,post_status,comment_status,ping_status,post_password,post_name,to_ping,pinged,post_modified,post_modified_gmt,post_content_filtered,post_parent,guid,menu_order,post_type,post_mime_type,comment_count,cidade,estado,cod_categoria,categoria,plano_comercial) 
VALUES 
(1099,1","2013-11-29 01:01:01","2013-11-29 01:01:01","www.cmgravatai.rs.gov.br    ","CÂMARA MUNICIPAL DE VEREADORES DE GRAVATAI","","publish","closed","closed","","camara-municipal-de-vereadores-de-gravatai","","","2013-11-29 01:01:01","2013-11-29 01:01:01","",0,"",0,"item","",0,"Gravataí","RS","6255","Câmaras Municipais",2);
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: And why are you trying to insert post using PhpMyAdmin ? Cant you use the WP admin panel or do it using code ?

Comment: next to values double quotes is missed `VALUES 
(1099,1",`

Comment: instead you try wp_insert_post

Comment: @SyedQarib Because I need to do the insertion of 30,000 posts, and this is not feasible through the panel (long).

I've tried several plugin, but match any of the free correctly makes the inclusion of custom fields.

Comment: @juergend no error during the execution, it is not only displayed on the page (it is displayed in the admin).

Comment: Try creating a script, this function will help : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: Tools / Export and Tools / Import do a fine and scaleable job of moving content from one WordPress instance to another. But unfortunately, if you've altered the core of WordPress drastically, you may have placed yourself beyond the pale where the community can help you.

Comment: Your custom fields need to be placed in the wp_postmeta table.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure, there are no fields in wp_posts table like:

`cidade,estado,cod_categoria,categoria,plano_comercial` and `cod_empresa`.

Check the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=94 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Hi @lolka_bolka,



yes, these are some custom fields that have created ... they usually work by including posts admin panel.



My question is whether I need to make the inclusion of data in other tables as wp_postmeta ...

Comment: **Never** modify the core of the wordpress, because, when there are any update, you can lose your changes. This is why are wp_postmeta table is. Sotre your custom data there.

Comment: @RicardoFredericoS.daSilva: I was first thinking about same topic as you posted. But inserting rows into `wp_posts` is not recommended, because there are some dependencies, i.e. Yoast plugin and so on. I've decided to prepare my data first and create a XML data file with all datasets. Then, I've used WP add-on "WP All Import" and "WP All Import - Yoast WordPress SEO Add-On" to import roundabout 500 pages in a batch process. This is more recommended and very solid way to import multiple pages or posts.